# How can I DRY up the code by shallowMounting the vue component in the beforeEach hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

For the first time, I'm implementing a bunch of unit tests in a Vue app using vue-test-utils. The tests do work, however, I'd like to DRY up the code.

At the moment I'm adding the following code to each of my tests:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(ConceptForm, {
    localVue,
    router,
    propsData: { conceptProp: editingConcept }
});
```

Making a test look something like this

```
it('shows the ctas if the state is equal to editing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(ConceptForm, {
        localVue,
        router,
        propsData: { conceptProp: editingConcept }
    });

    expect(wrapper.find('#ctas').exists()).toBe(true)
});
```

I'm doing this because I need to pass this specific propsData to the wrapper. Is there any way that I could shallowMount the component in the beforeEach and then pass the prop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could achieve what you want using the **[`setProps`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setprops)** function of the wrapper object. Consider the following example:

```
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(ConceptForm, {
        localVue,
        router,
        propsData: { conceptProp: editingConcept }
    });
});

it('shows the ctas if the state is equal to editing', () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ conceptProp: editingConcept });
    expect(wrapper.find('#ctas').exists()).toBe(true)
});
```